# Using VWO interface - how can I match all product URLs of a Magento site for an A/B test

Tags: magento, ab-testing, vwo

I am trying to setup an A/B test using the VWO interface for a Magento site.

I would like to target all product pages, but I do not see a clear way to match every single URL.

FYI, the products are using rewrite rules, eg:

- website.com/product-1
- website.com/some-other-product-name

I cannot use a regex as this would pick up other pages, eg:

- website.com/about-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following code to the pages you want to target.

```
var _vis_opt_url = 'http://website.com/my_pages_i_want_to_target';
```

The in VWO interface you can target that url.
https://vwo.com/knowledge/using-custom-urls/